# ChangeDate - Date Picker Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am trying to call ajax on DatePicker bootstrap changeDate event but after trying every possible way I am failed. Please help me. For testing I use console.log.

**Script :**

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.date-picker').datepicker();
        $('.date-picker').on('changeDate', function() {
            var date = $('#date-picker').val();
            console.log(123);
            return false; // for testing...
        });
    });
```

**HTML :**

```
<p class="_50">
                <label for="TitleID"><strong>Date </strong></label>
                <input name="date-picker" id="date-picker" value=""  class="date-picker"" type="text" class="required"  readonly="readonly"/>
            </p>
```

Comment: Show your AJAX call? Also tell us what _possible ways_ you tried? And where are you getting the error, if any?

Comment: Hello 
for testing I replaced ajax call with console.log(123);. I am even unable to fired changeDate event .


I am not getting any error. It is just now firing trigger.

Comment: Check your `class` attribute, `class="date-picker""`. Notice double quotes.

Comment: I tested your code. It works fine for me.

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/FTpYk/324/. Also you have an extra `"` in input tag `class="date-picker""`. Looks like you have not included a library.

Comment: I figured out Extra " but still not working.

Comment: If library wasn't included so calender should not be displaying but it is displaying. how else I can check if there is any issue with library.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that the `input` has been loaded and then initialize the plugin.

Try on window.load:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $('.date-picker').datepicker().
                    .on('changeDate', function() {
                       // Your ajax call
                    }); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Change "changeDate" to "change" simply:

```
<p>Date:
    <input id="datepicker" type="text">
</p>
$("#datepicker").datepicker().on('change', function() {
    alert("changed");
});
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddanone/D4AGz/492/)

Comment: the bootstrap-datepicker uses the `changeDate` event, not  `change` :)